# JMeter variable to List<String>

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

That's my JMeter variable:

```
workPackagesIds=["2487984","2487985","2487986"]
workPackagesIds_1=2487984
workPackagesIds_2=2487985
workPackagesIds_3=2487986
```

I'd like to use it in FOR EACH Sting loop in Post-procesor BeanShell.

```
String filepath ="C:\\result.csv";

f = new FileOutputStream(filepath, true);
p = new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p);

for(String workPackagesId : vars.get("workPackagesIds")){
    print(workPackagesId);
}

f.close();
```

But `vars.get("workPackagesIds")` it is not a `List<String>`.
How can I change it?

Expected result is to print eg: 2487984 or 2487985 etc...
Now I print:

```
["2487984","2487985","2487986"]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Switch to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor).
2. Use the following code

   ```
   vars.entrySet().each { var ->
      if (var.getKey().startsWith('workPackagesIds_')) {
          log.info(var.getValue())
      }
   }
   ```

   Demo:

   [image: JMeter Groovy Print Variables]

Be aware that it is [highly recommended to use the most performing scripting option](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) which is [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) as of now so consider migrating as soon as possible. More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you for response. That works! But I didn't expect so fast answer, meantime I edited my question. Sorry, for that.